# Can "last" here mean newest?

Tags: meaning

Context:
My word processor is **the last of a series of instruments** of self-expression that began with crayons and colored pencils held in my childish fist. My hands, somewhat grown, migrated to my mother's typewriter. [...] My parents bought a typewriter for me. [...] My next machine was an IBM word processor which has been in turn superceded by a Dell. Through all this relentlessly advancing technology...

(Link to the full article: "Young or old, a writer sends a book into the world ... " [Archive] - Absolute Write Water Cooler)

Question:
**Last** can sometimes mean **newest/most up-to-date**, as in **the last thing in fashion**, **the last thing in swimwear**...
It seems to be a fixed pattern: the last thing in something.

Can **last** mean **newest** in a structure like "**the last of a series of something**" as in my context?

Thank you.

Comment: "last" seems like "final" in this context, ie that you're saying there won't be any others.  I would say "most recent" instead.

Comment: I don't think last here is necessarily wrong, but I would usually say "the latest" in all of those examples.

Comment: Actually yes "the latest" is more idiomatic than "the most recent".

Answer (score 1):

If you say something is the last of something, it can either mean the newest in a series of something, or the only one from multiple things that is remaining.

1. "I liked the last Star Trek film" or "I was the last one to get onto the train" - both place the subject at the end of a sequence. However,
2. "Daniel was the last of the soldiers." could mean either he was the latest soldier, or he is the only solder remaining.

The example you provide places the typewriter at the end of a series, and therefore fits example 1.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. An unsupported answer may be removed.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Answer (score -1):

**Yes**.

According to the [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/last), "last" can mean:

> Most recent in time; latest.

When using as a noun (as in "the last of"), the meaning is:

> The last person or thing; the one occurring, mentioned, or acting after all others.

The article gives some examples, one which is particularly relevant for you:

> ‘Thought you had heard the last of the libel case involving some Borough staff at BoS?’

Comment: @Clare Thanks for the edit. Can you explain the reason for the downvote please?